# Fortran 2003, Select Type to Differentiate 'real' from 'real array'

Tags: oop, polymorphism, fortran

My question is, "Can a `select type` block be used to distinguish `real :: realInput` from `real :: realArrayInput(:)`?" It's clear how `select type` may be used to distinguish derived types, but becomes less clear to me how (or whether) it may be used on intrinsic types.

In Mad Libs form, can the blanks be filled in below to distinguish between the inputs above:

```
select type (input)
    type is (real)
        print *, "I caught the realInput"
    type is (___________)
        print *, "I caught the realArrayInput"
end select
```

I've found some related posts that did not quite contain the answer I was hoping for:

[Select Type Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329622/double-linked-list-in-fortran-type-is-not-judged-correctly)

[Determining Variable Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560182/fortran-determine-variable-type)

Comment: Perhaps you can accomplish your goal by passing the variable to an `elemental` procedure, or by writing a generic interface for two procedures.

Comment: could you just check the rank with the `rank` intrinsic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  `input` is either declared as an array or a scalar, even when it is polymorphic (and even when it is unlimited polymorphic).

The recent further interoperability with C TS (which may be part of F201X) introduced the concept of assumed rank and the RANK intrinsic, which may do what you want.  But there are many limitations around what can be done with assumed rank objects.  And regardless of that SELECT TYPE still only works on type.  The syntax of the select type construct simply doesn't permit specification of rank in the type guard statements.

Obviously depending on what it is that you actually want to do (?) ... and beyond generic interfaces mentioned by others, a way to have objects that can be either array or scalar in current Fortran (there are other possibilities) is to use derived type wrappers that are an extension of a common parent type.  You then use a polymorphic object declared as the parent type (or you can use an unlimited polymorphic object) to refer to an object of the relevant derived type.

```
TYPE :: parent
END TYPE parent

TYPE, EXTENDS(parent) :: scalar_wrapper
  REAL :: scalar_component
END TYPE scalar_wrapper

TYPE, EXTENDS(parent) :: array_wrapper
  REAL :: array_component(10)
END TYPE array_wrapper
...

SUBROUTINE what_am_i(object)
  ! Note that object is scalar, but that doesn't tell us 
  ! the rank of the components of the dynamic type of object.
  CLASS(parent), INTENT(IN) :: object
  !****
  SELECT TYPE (object)
  TYPE IS (scalar_wrapper)
    PRINT "('I am a scalar with value ',G0)",  &
        object%scalar_component
  TYPE IS (array_wrapper)
    PRINT "('I am an array with values ',*(G0,:,','))",  &
        object%array_component
  CLASS DEFAULT
    PRINT "('I am not sure what I am.')"
  END SELECT
END SUBROUTINE what_am_i
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. Could you confirm that I understand your meaning? It sounds like `type is (real)` is valid Fortran, but that **both** `real :: realInput` **and** `real :: realArrayInput(:)` would be considered `real` by the `select type` block, i.e., both would cause the above program (which I've just edited to make this comment clear) to print "I caught the realInput." If that's not what you mean, could you please clarify?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  SELECT TYPE only works on type.

Answer (score 2):

Just to combine [IanH's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22316412/1859258) and M.S.B's comment and explain more in detail: You can not use the `select type` construct to distinguish between real scalars and real arrays as they only differ in their *dimension*, but not in their *type*. When you declare your variable `input`, you already decide 'for ever', whether it has or it has not the `dimension` attribute:

```
class(*) :: input_scalar
class(*), dimension(10) :: input_array
```

Whichever value the variable takes later (or to whichever object it points to, if it is a pointer), it can not represent something with a dimensionality (rank) different from the one in its declaration.

On the other hand, you could for example use the `interface` construct (or `generic` in type bound procedures) to distinguish between objects of the same type but different ranks. The example below demonstrates that for scalar and rank one integer and real arrays.

```
module testmod
  implicit none
  interface typetest
    module procedure typetest0, typetest1
  end interface typetest
contains
  subroutine typetest0(object)
    class(*), intent(in) :: object
    select type(object)
    type is (real)
      print *, "real scalar"
    type is (integer)
      print *, "integer scalar"
    end select
  end subroutine typetest0

  subroutine typetest1(object)
    class(*), dimension(:), intent(in) :: object
    select type(object)
    type is (real)
      print *, "real array"
    type is (integer)
      print *, "integer array"
    end select
  end subroutine typetest1
end module testmod

program test
  use testmod
  implicit none

  integer :: ii
  integer, dimension(10) :: iarray

  call typetest(ii)      ! invokes typetest0
  call typetest(iarray)  ! invokes typetest1

end program test
```